# Who are the characters on the cover of the Boys vol4, We gotta go now?

Tags: character-identification, cover-art, the-boys

The below image is the cover of the Boys Volume 4, We gotta go now.

Who are all the individual characters on the front cover.

[image: We Gotta Go cover]

Comment: "*G-Force, G-Coast, G-Style, G-Wiz, the G-Brits and the G-Nomads"*

Comment: And, of course, members of The Boys are out there, and their dog.